# Consider round trip identically

Tags: r

I'm having difficulty for encoding the route variable in R in a way that it assumes a unique value when the route is the same, regardless of the origin and destination point (The origin is the first 4 characters of the variable route and the destination is the last 4). The base is as follows:

```
base <- data.frame(route = c("SBAA - SBBE", "SBAA - SBBR", "SBAA - SBCI",
                            "SBBE - SBAA", "SBBE - SBBR", "SBBR - SBBE"),
                   seats = c(1231, 1021, 715, 989, 759, 695))
base <- as_tibble(base)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
      route        seats
      <chr>           <dbl>
    1 SBAA - SBBE     1231
    2 SBAA - SBBR     1021
    3 SBAA - SBCI      715 
    4 SBBE - SBAA      989 
    5 SBBE - SBBR      759 
    6 SBBR - SBBE      695
```

I thought of doing a transformation to generate the variable code:

```
code <-as.numeric (as.factor (route))
```

However, the output will be different for same routes (same connecting airports) but with reverse origin and destination airports. For example, "SBAA - SBBE" and SBBE - SBAA "
 should have the same code, but will look like this:

```
  route           seats       code
  <chr>           <dbl>       <dbl>
1 SBAA - SBBE     1231         1
2 SBAA - SBBR     1021         2
3 SBAA - SBCI      715         3
4 SBBE - SBAA      989         4
5 SBBE - SBBR      759         5
6 SBBR - SBBE      695         6
```

I need routes that have the same connecting airports to have the same code, so that the code variable returns the following result:

```
  route           seats       code
  <chr>           <dbl>       <dbl>
1 SBAA - SBBE     1231         1
2 SBAA - SBBR     1021         2
3 SBAA - SBCI      715         3
4 SBBE - SBAA      989         1
5 SBBE - SBBR      759         4
6 SBBR - SBBE      695         4
```

Note that the code for "SBAA - SBBE" is identical to "SBBE - SBAA". Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't have time to write out the code, but try `separate` route into two columns, and then repasting them after `sort`. Now the return trip will be identical.

Comment: The 4th element is having a typoe `SBEE` instead of `SBBE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we extract the words, `sort`, `paste` and then do the `factor` to `integer`, it should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
base %>% 
    mutate(code = as.integer(factor(map_chr(str_extract_all(route, 
          "\\w+"), ~ str_c(sort(.x), collapse=" - ")))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Same idea of sorting, done by lapplying over the list of functions list(pmin, pmax), applying them to the strsplit of the first column to create two columns with each row now sorted. Then the "code" column is the group number when grouping by the new 2 columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(base)

base[, code := 
  base[, lapply(.(pmin, pmax), do.call, tstrsplit(route, ' - '))
      ][, g := .GRP, .(V1, V2)][['g']]
]

base
#          route seats code
# 1: SBAA - SBBE  1231    1
# 2: SBAA - SBBR  1021    2
# 3: SBAA - SBCI   715    3
# 4: SBBE - SBAA   989    1
# 5: SBBE - SBBR   759    4
# 6: SBBR - SBBE   695    4
```

Or (same output)

```
base[, code := .GRP, 
     interaction(lapply(list(pmin, pmax), do.call, tstrsplit(route, ' - ')))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
base <- data.frame(route = c("SBAA - SBBE", "SBAA - SBBR", "SBAA - SBCI",
                             "SBEE - SBAA", "SBEE - SBBR", "SBBR - SBEE"),
                   seats = c(1231, 1021, 715, 989, 759, 695))
base <- as_tibble(base)

library(data.table)
base <- as.data.table(base)
base[, code:=paste0(sort(c(str_split(route, " - ")[[1]][1],str_split(route, " - ")[[1]][2])), collapse=" - "), by=1:nrow(base)]
```